# Find and replace in Papeeria

Tags: editors, online

I'm using the online LaTex editor *Papeeria* for working on shared online LaTeX-files with collaborators. I just realized that I don not know how to "find & replace" terms. I found out that "⌘ + F" allows me to find items, but nowhere do I find a way to replace them too.

Does someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Hm, hard to find any docu. Just a guess: "⌘ + R" or "⌘ + r" ? // I'd send a not-so-kind Feedback to them ...

Comment: How di I find the  symbol at the start of "... +R" or "... +r" ? I have never come across it before.

Comment: @PeterWilson `albatross ⌘` says " Unicode glyph with code points [2318] mapping to [⌘] (AND search)". It seems it's also called "place of interest sign" https://decodeunicode.org/u+2318 (It's how one of the mod shift keys is marked on Apple PCs)

Comment: I understood the symbal as the command-key on some MAC/Apple keyboards, left and right to the space bar, see image; https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/MK2A3B?wid=572&hei=572&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&.v=1628010482000 // Would probably be the key with the window-icon on a PC-keyboard. /// But the real problem is minimalistic documentation of the editor: http://docs.papeeria.com/shortcuts/ (try the menu-icon)

Comment: Ctrl+H is the standard find and replace shortcut in many applications in Linux and Windows, I just tested that it also works in Papeeria when using the site from Linux. Maybe on Mac it would be ⌘ + H or ⌘ + Shift + F.

Comment: I use the LinuX  operating system. Apple and Mac are completely alien. Why is it assumed that everyone uses Mac code? I remember one Christmas visiting several  homes of MAC/MS developers in the Seattle area, all of whom had comprehensive manual s about Linux. If they tried to replicate they failed. Don't mind me as I am an old curmudgeoion.

Comment: @PeterWilson I share your sentiment fully - however in this particular question the asker mentioned the ⌘ symbol, therefore all the commenters assumed that we were talking about an Apple keyboard and OS.

Comment: @Marijn: Unfortunately, none of the commands work on Mac :-(